# React Native expo, apk build error: sdkVersion is missing from app.json

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am getting this error: "sdkVersion is missing from app.json" after doing exp build:android in my React Native expo app.
Here is my app.json

```
    {
  "expo": {
    "name": "Parallel Desk",
    "slug": "RN-ParallelDesk",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android", "web"],
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],

    "android": {
      "package": "com.paralleldesk.paralleldesk",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "icon": "./assets/icon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: error and code]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to add "sdkVersion" into your app.json

my app.json looks like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "test-app",
    "slug": "test-app",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "36.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "description": "",
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "backgroundColor": "#B2D235"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The sdkVersion can be found in the package json.